# Will Apple approve adding 'Refresh'-button to tab bar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, appstore-approval

Does anyone know if Apple approve apps with a button in a tab bar that just refreshes the current view and not change the actual view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. The Tab Bar is a very well understood metaphor - like tabs in a folio. Using  a tab as a button is definitely not expected behavior.

I'd recommend a `UINavigationBar` with a button to refresh.

EDIT:

This is a direct quote from [Apple's HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1#Bars):

> **Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the current mode or screen.** 
>   
> If you need to provide controls for your users, use a toolbar instead.

Comment: Johan, I feel as though it may be in your best interest to check out the hig - the answer you're looking for is clear. I'll include a screenshot in my answer. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1#Bars

Comment: I completely agree with @Aurum, tab bar should not be used as refresh button. Please check the IOS developer library for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately nobody here will be able to give you a definite answer on this. You might even have different results when submitting the app depending on who does the review, or it may change from one version to another when updating.

It clearly violates Apple's HIG, and I'm not sure I have seen many apps use a similar approach.

One thing I know for sure: I much prefer developers stick to the HIG and *not* do these type of "customizations". In fact, this annoyance might make me chose a competing product instead.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Apple will approve it. There is no problem with this.

Comment: Have you successfully implemented this in an app available att AppStore?